# How to download shared file from Google Drive using a link?

Tags: google-drive-api

For example we have a link to Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o4bqvKsGjf_yukzt-zQPtZWtqv21gpmv/view?usp=sharing

This file on someone's drive, not on my own. And how to download this file using API, if I know only a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The share with me link that you can get via the google drive web application. is not a true form of sharing.

In order to download a file using the api you must first have permission to access that file.   That being said you must have a record on the file with your username (email address) returned by a [premissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) call on the file.

Without it when you do a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) the file will not show up as you do not have permissions on the file.

The issue with the share with me link is that the Id is not the id of the file. So even if the file was public you would not be able to find it.

To be clear a share with me link to a file on google drive does

1. not contain the true file id needed for the api
2. grant any true permissions on the file. meaning that you cant access it via the api.

Comment: So is it impossible to download a file using only a link?

Comment: Not with the api no. If you click the link though you should be able to make a copy of the file and store it on your own account.  Then you will be able to access your copy of it via the api.   If you want to access it with the api they need to do a full share of the file and not just give you the share with me link.